# Android - onclick keeps crashing on emulator api 19, works fine elsewhere

Tags: android

I tried my app on API 23 on real device, API 25 emulator, API 26 emulator and then also API 19 emulator. It keeps crashing on the last one and works fine on the others.

From the mainfest
minSdkVersion 19 
targetSdkVersion 26

My XML defines the onclick like so for a custom button where I change the font style -

```
<com.ta.squltra.MyButton
    android:id="@+id/okButton"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_60sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
    android:text="OK"
    android:background="@drawable/chalkbutton"
    android:onClick="okButtonClicked"
    style="@style/taWhiteLargeButtonText"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
```

My .java for the above xml -

```
public void okButtonClicked(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, QuizActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_CATEGORY, gameMode);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();

}
```

And the code for the MyButton class, in case it matters -

```
public class MyButton extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton 
{
public MyButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    init();
}

private void init(){
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Filmcryptic.ttf");
    setTypeface(tf);

}
}
```

And finally the logcat output (edited) -

```
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
07-05 21:34:21.078 1538-1538/com.ta.squltra E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ta.squltra, PID: 1538
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method okButtonClicked(View) in the activity class android.support.v7.widget.TintContextWrapper for onClick handler on view class com.ta.squltra.MyButton with id 'okButton'
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3810)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: okButtonClicked [class android.view.View]
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:857)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3803)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
07-05 21:34:21.078 468-781/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.ta.squltra/.InfoScreenActivity
07-05 21:34:21.462 474-474/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 508K, 16% free 3139K/3708K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
```

Comment: What's your log cat saying

Answer (score 0):

Extend

> Button

instead of

> android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton

in you MyButton class.

Comment: Android Studio immediately complains that "This custom view should extend android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton instead"